# MFT camera with quick focus point choice

Tags: camera-settings, mirrorless, focus-point-selection

I used to have a Canon DSLR camera which allowed a quick selection between 9 different focus point with a nub on the back (1 for each direction and center) or a wheel to cycle.

I now have a Panasonic G7 mirrorless camera where switching points requires a "scrolling" action which moves the focus point until the desired location is reached.

I prefer the quick cycling ability so much that I'm considering getting a different camera. Do any M43 cameras have the sort of quick focus point selection that Canon had?

Comment: I don't know that particular camera, but have you checked you can't reduce the number of points in the settings? Sometimes that's all it needs - a million points is useful for 'full auto' but not necessarily for 'I'm in control'.

Comment: Are you opposed to touchscreen selection of focus points? That's faster than any method of pointing with a nub. Micro 4/3 cameras with that feature shouldn't be too hard to find on Google. the first hit for me was a Panasonic G3, which is from at least 2014. So there ought to be many newer choices since then.

Comment: @scottbb Yes, I prefer to shoot with the smaller viewfinder.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't seem to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When using the smaller viewfinder, the touchscreen remains active and can be used to select a focus point with, for example, your dominant hand thumb.

This mechanism works with both Panasonic and Olympus MFT cameras.